# ffmpeg forgets second time trimmed audio stream

Tags: ffmpeg

a.mp3 is a 2:36 duration long audio file. I was doing the following with it:

```
ffmpeg -i a.mp3 -filter_complex "[0]atrim=duration=10[first],[0]atrim=start=10:end=15[second],[first][second]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1[out1],[second][first]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1[out2],[out1][out2]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1" k.mp3
```

It hopefully does the following

1. get stream `first` cut from 0 to 10 of a.mp3
2. get stream `second` cut from 10 to 15 of a.mp3
3. concatenate the streams first and second (in that order) to stream `out1`
4. concatenate the streams second and first (in that order) to stream `out2`
5. concatenate the streams `out1` and `out2` to output file k.mp3

But it throws an error saying there is no stream named second

```
[mp3 @ 0x55858d01b580] Invalid stream specifier: second.
    Last message repeated 1 times
```

I know I can directly concatenate first+second+second+first to get the intended result k.mp3, I did do that

`ffmpeg -i a.mp3 -filter_complex "[0]atrim=duration=10[first],[0]atrim=start=10:end=15[second],[first][second][second][first]concat=n=4:v=0:a=1" k.mp3`

It didnt work either, it throws the same error. I want to know why it says stream specifier 'second' is invalid when there does exist a stream specifier 'second'. If 'second' is invalid and throws an error then why doesn't 'first' throw an error, it is even used before the second is used.

Comment: ffmpeg -i a.mp3 -filter_complex "[0]atrim=duration=10[first],[0]atrim=start=10:end=15[second],[first][second][second][first]concat=n=4:v=0:a=1" k.mp3 just realized this doesnt work either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your problem is that `second` has already been consumed.

You may get more mileage out of `splitting` the input to create multiple copies, which will provide you with enough inputs to handle the following filters.

Something like:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -filter_complex "[0]asplit=4[f1][f2][s1][s2];[f1]atrim=duration=10[f1out];[f2]atrim=start=10:end=15[f2out];[s1]atrim=duration=10[s1out];[s2]atrim=start=10:end=15[s2out];[f1out][f2out]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1[out1];[s2out][s1out]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1[out2];[out1][out2]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1" k.mp3
```